# Multithreading EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am currently writing a web app when I need to run a method simultaneously on a large number of threads.  I have constructed the method and it calls an Async EJB however, only 6 EJBs are spawned.  Are there some settings in Glassfish other that the EJB pool size that I sould be chnaging to allow more EJBs threads to be spawned?

Thanks

Comment: Are the EJBs stateful?

Comment: No they are @Stateless

Comment: So why do you want more beans?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a **Max Thread Pool Size** setting that you may want to check.

Configurations->configuration-name->Thread Pools->thread-pool-name as stated in the [Glassfish documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abehk.html#abefn).

Comment: Tried that, no use